# How to install PHP in mini-httpd server on MIPS platform?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, mips, mini-httpd

I have a MIPS board, It has mini-httpd server. I want to install PHP to it without MySQL [just basic support of PHP is enough but PHP should be work on browser].
Do I need to cross-compile the PHP source for MIPS? Or is there any alternative option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a mips tool chail and used lighttpd server instead of mini-httpd ... Solved my problem :)